# Extract a variable string from a .txt file

Tags: c#, python, batch-file, scripting

We have a customer who uses some of our equipment and outputs a particular string which we use as diagnostics.

However the customer in question has used their own logging system which fills the output files with lots of random stuff which is irrrelevant to us.

What I'm after is extracting a variable string at various locations and putting those extracted stings into a new text file.

Here is the variable sting I'm after:

```
*X;3;194; 0;2;125;0;0012;32;0;261D3;??
```

As mentioned this text can vary with its contents but will always start with `*X` and is generally no longer than 38 characters (including spaces and `;`)

An example of the text is...

```
2018-01-15 11:16:43.566 pid=2800 tid=17 ResultReader [INFO ] packet received: *X;3;194; 0;2;126;0;0012;32;0;26357;??
2018-01-15 11:16:43.566 pid=2800 tid=17 ResultReader [ERROR] Device reset - Critical error: BALL_IN_THE_SAME_DIRECTION_WITH_WHEEL_ROTOR
2018-01-15 11:16:43.567 pid=2800 tid=17 events [INFO ] EmitEvent - RolWheelStatusRelayMsg{PreviousPacket=Protocol: EXTENDED, State: FINISH_BETTING, GameCount: 194, WinningNumber: 0, WarningFlags: [BALL_IN_THE_SAME_DIRECTION_WITH_WHEEL_ROTOR], RotorSpeed: 12, RotorDirection: CLOCKWISE, ExtendedFlags: [ROTOR_RUNNING_AT_LEGAL_SPEED, ROTOR_ROTATING_CLOCKWISE], SpinCounter: 49, BallDirection: CLOCKWISE, BallSpeed: 12, BallInPocketPosition: -1, Packet=Protocol: EXTENDED, State: FINISH_BETTING, GameCount: 194, WinningNumber: 0, WarningFlags: [BALL_IN_THE_SAME_DIRECTION_WITH_WHEEL_ROTOR], RotorSpeed: 12, RotorDirection: CLOCKWISE, ExtendedFlags: [ROTOR_RUNNING_AT_LEGAL_SPEED, ROTOR_ROTATING_CLOCKWISE], SpinCounter: 50, BallDirection: CLOCKWISE, BallSpeed: 12, BallInPocketPosition: -1}
2018-01-15 11:16:44.067 pid=2800 tid=17 ResultReader [INFO ] packet received: *X;3;194; 0;2;126;0;0012;32;0;26357;??
```

The text in-between can vary but the goal is still the same. I don't mind how but would need to be executable for different files which can and may have different information. *(If that makes sense)*.

Comment: So have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Can you define a regular expression that would capture this string? E.g. https://regex101.com/r/XjjNoF/1

Comment: Does your string always end with double question marks(??)?

Comment: Why `C#` and `Python`? Don't spam with tags

Comment: @Equalsk No, as I didn't know where to start and from reading the other posts nothing seemed to fit what I wanted.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm not sure what it is you mean.

Comment: @j5Dev Not always no.

Comment: @AleksAndreev Doesn't have to be those. Happy with batch or anything really. If it works.

Comment: FYI that's why your question was closed and downvoted. Showing no effort is bad form. Given that the first result for `c# search for text` on your favourite search engine gives several ideas you could have at least tried one.

Comment: @Equalsk Wow. So for those of us that aren't coding focused and don't know what we're looking for so come to something like this only to get told we aren't bothering. Thanks. I'll try and search elsewhere

Comment: I'm confused. You're saying that you're surprised that a coding focused website requires you to have some degree of coding knowledge? Even if you knew nothing about coding you could have still done that search and showed that you had at least tried. SO is intended to be the last resource you try when you're stuck, not the first when you're not even sure which language to use. Good luck, hope you find what you need :-)

Comment: No I'm saying that after my search, evidently looking for the wrong thing and not able to find anything that seems to do what I'm trying to achieve I thought I'd come and ask on here knowing that someone would be able to help. Or at least try. I spent a few good hours trying to find what I needed and as you mentioned as a last resort came here. The solution that Loric posted below looks like the output I'm after. But I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: As others have said, I can see the point why it was downvoted. The answer I gave, whilst not being a 'copy/paste' solution, should enable you to get where you need to be. Programming is often the art of, as Dr Malcom put it, 'Standing on the shoulders of others' ;)

Answer (score 1):

If using regex, the following would do it for you...

```
/\*X.*\?\?/g
```

Identify the start of your string (\*X) then match any character 0 or more times (.*) up until the double question marks(\?\?).

The initial * character and ? symbols are escaped to prevent their default meaning being interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like that :

```
import re

with open('logfile.txt') as f: # assuming your log file name is logfile.txt...
    for line in f:
        ret = re.search('X.{36,40}\n$', line) # Here I take all starting with X, 36 to 40 length string and ending with a newline
        if ret is None:
            continue
        extracted_var = ret.group(0).strip()
        print(extracted_var)
```

With your sample of log file it outputs :

```
X;3;194; 0;2;126;0;0012;32;0;26357;??
X;3;194; 0;2;126;0;0012;32;0;26357;??
```